# Leibniz Algebras in physics

Tags: lie-algebras

Leibniz Algebras now appear in math-physics c.f.tensor hierarchies.
The n-lab entry Leibniz Algebras for does not provide links to physics
When did they first appear in the physics list? or, if long ago,
when did the recent resurgence start?

This needs a tag Leibniz-algebra